# One out of two Document property not inserted in a mongoDB collection using: Mongoose and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

A Nodejs server application gets Name and Age from an HTML form (with post method) and with the help of ExpressJS and Mongoose has to create a MongoDB document. That works but Age is not written in the document of the collection. Please help me to fix it.

Here are the files with the code:
personform.html located in: C:\Program Files\nodejs\myapp\public
4.6-mongo.js in: C:\Program Files\nodejs\myapp
Person.js (mongoose schema and MongoDB connectio details) placed in: C:\Program Files\nodejs\myapp
created.ejs (ejs) in: C:\Program Files\nodejs\myapp\views
MongoDB is installed in: C:\Program Files

personform.html

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action='/create' method='post'>
      Name: <input name='name'>
    <p>
      Age: <input age='age'>
    <p>
    <input type=submit value='Submit Form!'>
  </form>
 </body>  
</html>
```

4.6-mongo.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var Person = require('./Person.js');
app.use('/create', (req, res) => {
    var newPerson = new Person ({
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age,
        });
    newPerson.save( (err) => { 
        if (err) {
            res.type('html').status(500);
            res.send('Error: ' + err);
        }
        else {
            res.render('created', {person : newPerson});
        }
        } ); 
});
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use('/', (req, res) => { res.redirect('/public/personform.html'); } );
app.listen(8000,  () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 8000');
    });
```

Person.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var personSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    age:  Number
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
personSchema.methods.standardizeName = function() {
    this.name = this.name.toLowerCase();
    return this.name;
}
```

created.ejs

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your form and specifically your age input. It should be `name="age"`

```
<form action='/create' method='post'>
      Name: <input type="text" name='name'>
    <p>
      Age: <input type="text" name='age'>
    <p>
    <input type=submit value='Submit Form!'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. that was an error of mine when I copied the HTML from an example of the course I'm attending. I wonder if you know what is that " __v Int32"  that follows the Name property? It is there even after the fix.

Comment: __v is about versionKey that is created per document by Mongoose. Is it appeared anything else except from mongo Compass?

Comment: Yes, in the NodeJS cmd window there is just the { _id: 5cc337fd9b6e8e0f98e831d1, name: 'Mike', age: 35 } that is the last document inserted.

Comment: In case you don't need it, you can set it to false in your mongoose Schema `versionKey: false`